# read and write in a file android

Tags: android, file

I have next problems:

(1) How to check whether a file exists ? I do it this way in `MainActivity` `onCreate`

```
File f = new File("punteggio.txt");
if(f.exist())
   readFromFile();
else{
    writeToFile();
    readFromFile();
}
```

but it does not work because every time I open my application file does not exist.

(2) Another problem.
In my first activity I write and read from the file without problems, while in the second activity when I read from the file the string is empty .

Main activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textRecord);
    File f = new File("punteggio.txt");
    if (!f.exists()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Writeee");
        writeToFile();
    } else {
        readFromFile();
    }
}

private void readFromFile() {
    String ret = "";
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("punteggio.txt");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) fis.getChannel().size()];
        fis.read(buffer);
        String str = "";
        for (byte b : buffer) str += (char) b;
        fis.close();
        Log.d(TAG, str);
        textScore.setText("Record: " + str);
        Log.i("STACKOVERFLOW", String.format("GOT: [%s]", str));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("STACKOVERFLOW", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public void startGame(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GamePanel.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

private void writeToFile() {
    String string = "0";
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("punteggio.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(string.getBytes());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

This is the secondActivity

```
private int readFromFile() {
    String str = "";
    int i = 0;

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("punteggio.txt");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) fis.getChannel().size()];
        fis.read(buffer);
        for (byte b : buffer) str += (char) b;
        i = Integer.parseInt(str);
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("STACKOVERFLOW", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Stringa iiiii: " + i);
    return i;
}
```

The variable is empty, why?
Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer for (1) - opening and writing to file depend on where the file is located, it could be in phone storage OR in SD Card. as such, when implementing reading files system, care should be taken considering the location of the file. This, sometime will cause the error, cannot locating the file.
Alternatively, a better way of doing it would be using share preference.

sidenote : storing game score in a text file is vulnerable because user can directly edit the scores in the text file and alter the game result.

Comment: share preference is a way of storing values in pair... more information here ->  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: the data will be persistence throughout. when the app is CLOSED, the value stay there. the values will be lost, when user clean data (from setting) or uninstall the app. If you are referring to activity ON DESTROY, then worry not, the value is still stored. By the way, you should look at how you want to store your values, whether the user login to your game, and retrieve their scores from a server, or they can only keep the scores in mobile phones. ~ cheers ~

Comment: The value must be stored on the phone and when you reopen the application value will be taken

Comment: well yes then, share preference is recommended, of course, there are some other ways.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your time dedicated =)

Comment: you are welcome. there are many share preferences examples here, check them out... here's a tutorial to start with...->>https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjurOb3gaDKAhVVjo4KHTtLA8sQFggvMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialspoint.com%2Fandroid%2Fandroid_shared_preferences.htm&usg=AFQjCNFkrejn6fkQQFEBvP_QzTXaEVFYjg&sig2=eqaUQ8F0j_g4QXobLPLGLw&bvm=bv.111396085,d.c2E

Comment: On the site of Android do not explain to perfection. I'm Italian and so it is difficult to find guides in English . Thank you